# How to close all open instances of a modeless dialog box?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# winform project that displays a list of results based on a user's search criteria. For each item on the list, the user can open a modeless dialog box showing more details about the selected item.

Every time the user opens an instance of my details window, this code runs:

```
public void showDetails()
{
    GetDetails route = new GetDetails();
    route.myParent = this;
    route.Show();
}
```

In order to compare details between two or more items, the user is allowed to open as many instances of this dialog box as it likes. I'd like to be able to close any and all open instances of this window when the user conducts a new search from the main form window? I've tried Googling, but no luck ... does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What about keeping a list of screens you open? Then iterate over it and close the forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Application.OpenForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx) is a collection of open forms owned by the application

try find all details dialogs and close them like this:

```
foreach(var f in Application.OpenForms.OfType<GetDetails>().ToList())
{
    f.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really tell, but I assume your GetDetails is a System.Windows.Forms.Control (probably a form, a dialog box, a message box, etc).

If you look closely to your Form.InitializeComponent, you'll see that Form has a property Controls. All child controls are added to the control collection.

If you add each created route to your control collection you can ask this collection for all objects of type GetDetails and order them to close:

```
public void ShowDetails()
{
    var route = new GetDetails();
    route.myParent = this;
    this.Controls.Add(route);
    route.Show();
}

public void CloseAllRoutes()
{
    foreach (var route in this.Controls.Where( control => control is GetDetails))
    {
        route.Close();
    }
}
```

You need to be certain that when a rout is closed, or disposed or something the following code is called:

```
private void OnRouteClosed (object sender, ...)
{
    if (sender is GetDetails)
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(sender);
    }
}
```